# Conditionally update Data Frame column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to update a column from a value of 0 to a value of 1 if certain conditions are true. Here is my code:

```
df_['win'] = 0
df_.loc[df_['predicted_spread'] > df_['vegas_spread'] and df_['actual_spread'] > df_['vegas_spread'], 'win'] = 1
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Does anybody have any ideas of what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing boolean indexing you need to use the logical operator for `and` which is `&`. See the doc [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for more info

```
df['win'] = 0
cond_1 = df['predicted_spread'] > df['vegas_spread']
cond_2 = df['actual_spread'] > df['vegas_spread']
df.loc[cond_1 & cond_2, 'win'] = 1
```

Basically just your answer with `&` instead of `and`. I just rewrote it to make it a little clearer.

Comment: Works brilliantly! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
df_['win'] = 0
df_.loc[df_['predicted_spread'].gt(df_['vegas_spread']) and df_['actual_spread'].gt(df_['vegas_spread']), 'win'] = 1
```